# Comparing values of list of tuples, current and next

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I have a list of tuples based off a training data set.

```
empty = [(a time, a crime),(a time, a crime),(...,...).....]
```

I'd like to check that if the current time in the current tuple is equal to the current time in the next tuple, print the time and a crime.

I had this previously which would print all the items in a list if the current and next values were the same, but I don't think this will work if I want to restrict it to filter on the time alone, rather than the whole list value. Unsure if there is anything I can do with the split function or if passing the data into a list of tuples was the right way to go. Would really appreciate any help.

where:

```
empty = ["a time, a crime", "a time, a crime"....]


for next_obj in empty:
    if next_obj[0] == cur_obj[0]:
        print cur_obj
    else:
        pass
    cur_obj = next_obj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
crimes_and_times = [('a time', 'a crime'), ('b time', 'b crime'), ('b time', 'c crime')]
for i in xrange(1, len(crimes_and_times)):
    cur = crimes_and_times[i]
    prev = crimes_and_times[i - 1]
    if cur[0] == prev[0]:
        print cur
```

output:

```
('b time', 'c crime')
```

Comment: tell you what, I do. Works great, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)